# nginx rewrite subdomain to www except if url contains string

Tags: regex, nginx

I'm trying to redirect with nginx all urls with the subdomain "admin" to www, except for the ones containing "wp-admin".

The behavior should be the following:

-`https://admin.domainname.com/slug` => `https://www.domainname.com/slug`

-`https://admin.domainname.com/wp-admin/slug` => no redirect

I tried the following one but it's not working:

```
rewrite ^(?!/[^/]+/wp-admin/)(/.*)admin(\?.*)?$ $1www$2 permanent;
```

I guess the `(/.*)admin(\?.*)` part is not correct. How can I capture the "admin" subdomain?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked:

```
if ($uri !~ "^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php)(.*)"){
  return 301 https://www.domainname.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answers only the regex part of the question.

The @IvanShatsky's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69071887/12610347) is more useful as it addresses the the main issue of the OP

---

Not sure about your exact requirements, but here is a quick fix:

```js
const rewrite = (url) => {
  const new_url = url.replace(/^(https|http):\/\/admin\.((.(?!\/wp-admin\/))*)$/, '$1://www.$2')
  console.log(new_url)
}
rewrite('https://admin.domainname.com/slug')
rewrite('https://admin.domainname.com/wp-admin/slug')
```

1. `(https|http)` - gets protocol
2. `:\/\/admin\.` - check if there is `://admin.`
3. `((.(?!\/wp-admin\/))*)` - gets every char until the end, if it is not followed by `/wp-admin/`, fails otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can't check domain name with the `rewrite` directive, it works with so-called *normalized* URI (in your examples it will be `/slug` or `/wp-admin/slug`). What you can do is to check `Host` HTTP header value:

```
if ($http_host = 'admin.domainname.com') {
    rewrite ^(?!/wp-admin)(.*)$ https://www.domainname.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it in a server { } bracket of my nginx config file, but it doesn't work. Any idea where I should put this piece of code exactly?

Comment: In nginx documentation terms it is called _context_. There can be **http** context (when the directive is placed under the `http { ... }` block), **server** context, **location** context, etc. You are right, this one should be placed under the `server` context. I don't know why it doesn't work first time, I'll give it a try later.

Comment: Everything is working as expected for me. [Here](https://pastebin.com/ShEReGyZ) is my nginx config for testing, [here](https://pastebin.com/P109Ux25) is `curl` execution log. Are you sure you add this configuration fragment to right `server` block? Can you add this block to your question or paste it somewhere (of course except real domain names or certificate files paths/names)?

Comment: Ok, maybe I found the issue. I deployed a website using Runcloud and they write it's a NGINX + Apache2 Hybrid configuration. Does that mean that I need to do the URL rewriting into .htaccess?

Comment: I don't think so, nginx should do the redirect before apache is involved into request processing. I'm afraid I can't help you further if you don't show your full nginx config.

Comment: Here is the extra-config.conf file I added in the extra.d folder (following RunCloud's instructions [here](https://runcloud.io/knowledgebase/articles/web-application/how-to-redirect-to-www-or-non-www)) : https://pastebin.com/jx5nVftd